# Guest account - stopping autostart applications

Tags: 17.04, guest-session

In Ubuntu 17.04 I've re-enabled the Guest account.

When the Guest account comes up, it launches some autostart applications that I don't want. I've looked in `/etc/skel` and `/etc/guest-session/skel` and I'm not finding where/how these applications are starting. I can see these applications in `~/.config/autostart` in the guest account.

How/where do these startup applications get loaded into the guest account upon initialization?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59469/discussion-on-question-by-heynnema-guest-account-stopping-autostart-applicatio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Command line methods:**

The autostart applications can be usually can be found in this directories:

```
~/.config/autostart
/etc/xdg/autostart/
```

So you can edit included files to prevent autostart applications.

For example I change `~/.config/autostart/print-applet.desktop` file to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Hidden=true
```

So it be disable at the startup.

Or as another example you can comment out `NoDisplay=true` line from `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-store.desktop` to disable autostart `tracker-store` application.

**GUI methods:**

1. In this method, type `Startup Applications` in `dash` and choose which aplications autostart or not.
2. The another GUI method is works only on some desktop environments
   like xfce;

   In this method at the first step run applications that you want to
   autostart and then  you can run `Session and Startup` application so
   in the `Session tab` click on `Save Session` button, and that
   application is autostarts after reboot.

**Change guest account settings:**

But in your case `Startup Applications` and the `~/.config/autostart` directory may not work because the guest account preferences are reset after reboot.

So this directories is can be helpful, because guest account settings are loaded from these directories:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/
/etc/skel
/etc/guest-session
```

Also these files can be helpful:

```
/etc/skel/.config/autostart
/etc/guest-session/skel
/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh
/usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh
```

But if you haven't such files (or directories) you can change the guest session settings by [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Special_purpose_user) way

> Using a special user account for setting the guest preferences is the
>   most convenient way to customize the guest session feature. Please
>   follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Add a new user account with the username guest-prefs.
>
> Log in to guest-prefs and change things to what you want your guests encounter at startup.
>
> Open a terminal window and create a symbolic link to the home directory of guest-prefs:
>
> sudo mkdir /etc/guest-session
> sudo ln -s /home/guest-prefs /etc/guest-session/skel
> ```
>
> Now, when you launch a guest session, it will have the same
>   preferences as you set for guest-prefs.